# How to go through ALL the elements of a list to check if it matches with something

Tags: python, list

List of tuples (let's call it `A`):

```
[('Hey', 'b', 'c'),
 ('Waddup', 'd', 'e'),
 ('Cutie', 'f', 'g')]
```

And I have another list of tuples (list `B`):

```
[('1', 'Hey', 'k'),
 ('2', 'Waddup', 'j'),
 ('3', 'Superman', 'h')]
```

I want to iterate over list `B` to see if `x[0]` (for `x` in list `A`) is in any of those tuples in list `B`. I already tried `any` and `all` built-ins, but it didn't work.

```
if all(x[0] not in B for x in A):
   return x[0]
```

Basically the only value I should get is `'Cutie'` since it's the only zeroth element of each list in list `A` that's not in list `B`. However, I get every element of that list (I believe it's checking element by element and not all of them in once).

Edit. Let's assume that IF my code was working, it would return `x[0]`.
So, it should ONLY return `'Cutie'`, once. Instead, it returns this:

```
'Hey'
'Hey'
'Waddup'
'Waddup'
'Cutie'
'Cutie'
'Cutie'
```

Comment: The paranthesis in `A` are not balanced if I am not mistaken; I guess that's just a typo?

Comment: Indeed :) my apologizes for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) for that (below is detailed, you can also merge it into one line to avoid the temporary sets):

```
a_0 = set(t[0] for t in A)

b_1 = set(t[1] for t in B)
```

giving

```
{'Cutie', 'Hey', 'Waddup'}
```

and

```
{'Hey', 'Superman', 'Waddup'}
```

Difference is then just

```
a_0 - b_1

{'Cutie'}
```

If you want to have your result as a list, you can do:

```
final_res =  list(a_0 - b_1)
```

which gives

```
['Cutie']
```

The compact version would be

```
final_res = list(set(t[0] for t in A) - set(t[1] for t in B))
```

Comment: It worked in perfection!! But is there any chance to remove those final {} ? Since I want to append the final result to list B and it wouldn't look nice if one element has {} around it.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
>> [a[0] for a in A if all(a[0] not in b for b in B)]
['Cutie']
```